# How to close Window Tab After Submitting a Form in Symfony?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony, twig

I'm submmiting a symfony Form in window tab. The submit button should close the window After submitting the Form and refresh the opener page. So i used jquery to do this Part.

```
$('#submitAndClose').on('submit', function () {
   setTimeout(
     function () {
        opener.location.reload(true);
        window.close();
     }
   , 3000);
})
```

But i guess because symfony refreshing the Page after subbmitting, the jquery is not working is expected.

And this is my Submit button in SymfonForm:

```
->add('saveAndClose', SubmitType::class, [
     'label' => 'Save and close',
])
```

Here is the twig part:

```
{{ form_widget(form.saveAndClose, {
    attr: {
        id: 'submitAndClose',
    }
}) }}
```

And this is the Controller Part as [Nico Hasse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1116230/nico-haase) requested more info:

```
/**
* @param Request $request
* @param int $id
*
* @return Response
*
* @Route("/{id}",  methods={"GET", "POST"})
*/
public function editAction(
    Request $request,
    int $id
): Response {

    $user = $this->em->getRepository(User::class)->find($id);
    $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $this->em->flush();
    }

    return $this->render('user/edit.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

Now when i submit the form it works but it does not close the Window.

The setTimeout was only for test but it is not necessary.
Any ideas?

Comment: why do you reload after submitting? Why not just closing the tab?

Comment: Please share more details. How is this related to PHP, Symfony, or Twig? None of them handle browser tabs

Comment: I don't understand why i got -1

Comment: @AngelDeykov is there any way to prevent reloading the page after submit?

Comment: @NicoHaase well OP has to close the tab after it's been sent to the server

Comment: Yeah, that's the part I understood. But still, neither PHP nor Symfony or Twig are able to close a tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use the timeout in order to close the tab.
What you could is pass a variable after the form has been processed, e.g. `close_window`, to the view. In the view you could then do the following instead of the timeout:

```
{% if close_window|default %}
    <script>window.close();</script>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank  you so much, you saved my day. I was looking to do it with ajax and rewriting my controller and everything. this way is much easier. @DarkBee

Answer (score 0):

Why do you reload the page? Since you reload the page it does not close, and you can do this with plain JavaScript.

```js
document.getElementById('saveAndClose').onclick = () => window.close();
```

But your case might be like [this picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9f2K.png)